# Regex.Replace using regular expression as replacement

Tags: c#, regex, algorithm, collections

I am new to C# programming language and came across the following problem
I have a string **" avenue 4 TH some more words"**. I want to remove space between 4 and TH. I have written a regex which helps in determining whether "4 TH" is available in a string or not.

> [0-9]+\s(th|nd|st|rd)

```
string result = "avanue 4 TH some more words";
var match = Regex.IsMatch(result,"\\b" + item + "\\b",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)  ;
Console.WriteLine(match);//True
```

Is there anything in C# which will remove the space

something like`Regex.Replace(result, "[0-9]+\\s(th|nd|st|rd)", "[0-9]+(th|nd|st|rd)",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);`

so that end result looks like

> avenue 4TH some more words

Comment: You could use 2 capturing groups and use those in the replacement `([0-9]+)\s(th|[nr]d|st)` https://regex101.com/r/PJYTsi/1

Comment: Something like `var match = string.Concat(Regex.Match(result, @"(?i)(\d+)\s*(th|[nr]d|st)\b")?.Groups.Cast<Group>().Skip(1));`

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
var pattern = @"(?i)(\d+)\s*(th|[nr]d|st)\b";
var match = string.Concat(Regex.Match(result, pattern)?.Groups.Cast<Group>().Skip(1));
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/s2lecW) yielding `4TH`.

The regex - `(?i)(\d+)\s*(th|[nr]d|st)\b` - matches 1 or more digits capturing the value into Group 1, then 0 or more whitespaces are matched with `\s*`, and then `th`, `nd`, `rd` or `st` as whole words (as `\b` is a word boundary) are captured into Group 2.

The `Regex.Match(result, pattern)?` part tries to match the pattern in the string. If there is a match, the match object `Groups property is accessed and all groups are cast to a`Group`list with`Groups.Cast()`. Since the first group is the whole match value, we`.Skip(1)` it.

The rest - the values of Group 1 and Group 2 - are concatenated with `string.Concat`.